# How do I get a list of registered entities in symfony2

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony

I've just started using symfony2 and I'd like to get a list of registered entities to search in two fields **title** and **description**.

i've multiple `Entities` as well as multiple `Admins` , some of them are mapped with **Symfony : Media** 
in single bundle (**FrontBundle**).

> Bundle with Entities structure.

```
FrontBundle
    ->Pages(Entity)
    ->Menus(Entity)
    ->Testimonials.(Entity)
```

Also i don't want to call `getRepository($entity)` everytime because it will run's multiple queries.

Any ideas on the best way to do that?

Answer (score 7):

To get all your mapped entities, I'd suggest using the entity manager:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$entities = $em->getConfiguration()->getMetadataDriverImpl()->getAllClassNames();
```

This should give you a list of full class names for your entities.
As far as using `getRepository($entity)` this isn't exactly possible, but you can either use the entity manager to get the shortcut name, or create a little helper function to do so, such as:

```
public function convertClassNameToShortcutNotations($className)
{
    $cleanClassName = str_replace('\\Entity', '\:', $className);
    $parts = explode('\\', $cleanClassName);

    return implode('', $parts);
}
```

which in combination with the list of entity classes the entity manager gave you should work:

```
foreach ($entities as $className) {
    $shortcut = $this->convertClassNameToShortcutNotations($className);
}
```

Provided your project structure is standard, this should all work without issue.